# endless SYN_RECV coming in on ipv4 interface w/ tcp6 protocol... syn flood attempt?

Tags: ipv6, tcpdump

I've moved the sites I host to a new machine, and am waiting for all traffic to go away on the old one before I shut it off.  The host is fedora 24 running on linode.  So I notice, there is only one IP number now hitting the machine, continuously, and I don't know what I'm looking at.   On my linode graph I see a steady traffic ping on the "tcp6" graph, so I look at netstat and I see this:

```
# netstat -nt
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0    236  ..... <my SSH connection to the machine> ...   ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 45.79.130.46:80         113.212.156.53:80       SYN_RECV
```

These messages keep occurring and there is no log in the apache logs, so it seems like some kind of abuse is being attempted on my server but I don't understand the nature of it.

Then running a tcpdump for the 113 number, this is what I see:

```
tcpdump -nv  -tttt -i eth0 -s 65535 port 80  and \( src  113.212.156.53 or dst 113.212.156.53 \)
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
2017-09-22 14:49:06.596326 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 171, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    113.212.156.53.http > 45.79.130.46.http: Flags [S], cksum 0x48e6 (correct), seq 2832531456, win 0, length 0
2017-09-22 14:49:06.596425 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 32829, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    45.79.130.46.http > 113.212.156.53.http: Flags [.], cksum 0x4169 (correct), ack 1890582529, win 29200, length 0
2017-09-22 14:49:06.597206 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 200, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    113.212.156.53.http > 45.79.130.46.http: Flags [S], cksum 0x8afc (correct), seq 1723793408, win 0, length 0
2017-09-22 14:49:08.737416 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 44)
    45.79.130.46.http > 113.212.156.53.http: Flags [S.], cksum 0xbda5 (incorrect -> 0x29ac), seq 2451913564, ack 1890582529, win 29200, options [mss 1460], length 0
2017-09-22 14:49:20.592584 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 69, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    113.212.156.53.http > 45.79.130.46.http: Flags [S], cksum 0x986c (correct), seq 1498349568, win 0, length 0
2017-09-22 14:49:20.592689 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 36687, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    45.79.130.46.http > 113.212.156.53.http: Flags [.], cksum 0x4169 (correct), ack 1, win 29200, length 0
2017-09-22 14:49:20.592722 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 80, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    113.212.156.53.http > 45.79.130.46.http: Flags [S], cksum 0x8e85 (correct), seq 1664483328, win 0, length 0
2017-09-22 14:49:35.705215 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 152, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    113.212.156.53.http > 45.79.130.46.http: Flags [S], cksum 0xddfc (correct), seq 331284480, win 0, length 0
2017-09-22 14:49:35.705303 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 37543, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    45.79.130.46.http > 113.212.156.53.http: Flags [.], cksum 0x4169 (correct), ack 1, win 29200, length 0
2017-09-22 14:49:35.753541 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 56, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    113.212.156.53.http > 45.79.130.46.http: Flags [S], cksum 0x6838 (correct), seq 2307063808, win 0, length 0
```

I don't know if this is some kind of attack. (EDIT: I think it's a syn flood attempt)

EDIT: the new server actually shows a lot more of these.  I've changed httpd to listen on 0.0.0.0 so that moves the SYN_RECV connections to "tcp" rather than "tcp6", and am trying out things in https://mithunkumr.wordpress.com/tag/syn-flood-attack/.

Comment: Google is you friend https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/237731/why-are-ipv4-tcp-connections-showing-as-tcp6

Comment: The connections are exactly 3 every 15 seconds. This is no synflood or attack. The IP is out of Japan "controlsrv" it reverses to visit.keznews.com and redirects to realtor.com. Any of these make sense?